# How to optimize or write correctly this MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql

Today noticed one SQL query that was extremely long in my mysql-slow.log

I would like to ask some SQL experts how to correctly format and perform this SQL.

**Idea behind sql:
Return all emails that are not in mailchimp table while doing it from 2 tables and return only DISTINCT values (users and subscribers emails might duplicate). Also including city and language with results.**

As you can see query_time is monster long and rows examined are just wtf combined 2 tables there should be only around 20k rows.

```
Query_time: 113.216544  Lock_time: 0.000180 Rows_sent: 43  Rows_examined: 208280841

SELECT * FROM 
    ( SELECT u.email AS email, u.city, u.language FROM users AS u 
        LEFT JOIN mailchimp AS m ON u.email = m.email WHERE m.email IS NULL GROUP BY u.email 
        UNION SELECT s.email AS email, s.city, s.language FROM subscribers AS s 
        LEFT JOIN mailchimp AS m ON s.email = m.email WHERE m.email IS NULL GROUP BY s.email ) 
    AS sync GROUP BY sync.email ORDER BY sync.email ASC;
```

EXPLAIN for query

```
+----+--------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type  | table      | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                           |
+----+--------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | <derived2> | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    23 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED      | u          | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 10482 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED      | m          | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 11411 | Using where; Not exists         |
|  3 | UNION        | s          | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  2709 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  3 | UNION        | m          | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 11411 | Using where; Not exists         |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union2,3> | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  NULL |                                 |
+----+--------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------+
6 rows in set (2 min 1.65 sec)
```

Comment: Sub-selects, unions, and order bys, oh my!

Comment: can you run those as two different queries and sort in the code? might be faster

Comment: Post an EXPLAIN for that query in question as well.

Comment: Is `users.email` UNIQUE in table `users` ? And in table `subscribers` ?

Comment: Add the indexes of the 3 tables in the question, please.

Comment: You see from the explain that he has no indexes defined.

Comment: @ypercube they are not UNUQUE check for that is made on php side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have no indexes on the three tables. Add index on field `email`, on all 3 tables; `users`, `subscribers` and `mailchimp` and run the query - and the EXPLAIN - again.

Your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  ( SELECT u.email AS email, u.city, u.language
    FROM users AS u 
      LEFT JOIN mailchimp AS m
        ON u.email = m.email
      WHERE m.email IS NULL
      GROUP BY u.email 
  UNION
    SELECT s.email AS email, s.city, s.language
    FROM subscribers AS s 
    LEFT JOIN mailchimp AS m
      ON s.email = m.email
    WHERE m.email IS NULL
    GROUP BY s.email
  ) 
  AS sync
GROUP BY sync.email
ORDER BY sync.email ASC;
```

could be written like this (removing the two inner `GROUP BY` and turning `UNION` into `UNION ALL` ):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  ( SELECT u.email AS email, u.city, u.language
    FROM users AS u 
      LEFT JOIN mailchimp AS m
        ON u.email = m.email
      WHERE m.email IS NULL
  UNION ALL
    SELECT s.email AS email, s.city, s.language
    FROM subscribers AS s 
    LEFT JOIN mailchimp AS m
      ON s.email = m.email
    WHERE m.email IS NULL
  ) 
  AS sync
GROUP BY sync.email
ORDER BY sync.email ASC;
```

or like this (turning the `LEFT JOIN - check IS NULL` into `NOT EXISTS`), which is sometimes faster:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  ( SELECT u.email AS email, u.city, u.language
    FROM users AS u 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT * 
        FROM mailchimp AS m
        WHERE u.email = m.email
      )
  UNION ALL
    SELECT s.email AS email, s.city, s.language
    FROM subscribers AS s 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT * 
        FROM mailchimp AS m
        WHERE s.email = m.email
      )
  ) 
  AS sync
GROUP BY sync.email
ORDER BY sync.email ASC;
```

In any case, **add indexes** to the `email` fields!

Comment: Thanks big time. now it is `6 rows in set (0.15 sec)`

Comment: @arma: Note that if an email is in both `users` and `subscribers` or multiple times in one of these tables, but the rows have different `city` or `language` stored, only one of the cities and languages will be shown. Remove the `GROUP BY`, if you want the multiple rows to be shown.

Comment: Yes i understand i should rewrite code that emails there should be UNIQUE and remove php check for that. Thanks again massive fix from 2m15sec to 0.15sec.

Answer (score 3):

Note in the explain plan that there are NO USABLE KEYS. This will make performance terrible. For EACH user record, you have to scan the entire mailchimp table. Then for EACH subscriber record, you scan the entire mailchimp table. You doing approximately 10482*11411 + 2709*11411 reads.

Maybe a MySQL expert can chime in here, but as I understand the MySQL documentation, it doesn't do hash matches like some other db engines. Everything is a loop and match.

You could probably dramatically improve performance by creating an index on mailchimp.email.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help without messing up your results?  I added UNION ALL, a plain UNION Is kind of wasted cycles since you're grouping in the outer query.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    ( SELECT u.email AS email, u.city, u.language FROM users AS u 
        LEFT JOIN mailchimp AS m ON u.email = m.email WHERE m.email IS NULL GROUP BY u.email 
        UNION ALL
      SELECT s.email AS email, s.city, s.language FROM subscribers AS s 
        LEFT JOIN mailchimp AS m ON s.email = m.email WHERE m.email IS NULL GROUP BY s.email ) 
    AS sync GROUP BY sync.email ORDER BY sync.email ASC;
```